# display different number on label vb

Tags: vb.net, random

i'm new in VB please help me.
Is it possible to display different numbers on a label? The text in the label needs to change every 100 milliseconds.

when you click the btnSpin random numbers will display on the label and when you click btnStop  it will stop and show the last number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First Add a timer,label,button to you form. then

In form Load event initialize the timer interval and start the timer

```
  Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Timer1.Interval = 100    '=100 milli seconds
        Timer1.Start()
    End Sub
```

In the timer tick event,

```
 Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Dim xRandNo As Random = New Random
        Label1.Text = xRandNo.Next()   'it will produce random number
    End Sub
```

Stop the timer in the button click

```
   Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSpin.Click
            Timer1.Stop()
    End Sub
```

Comment: @user2874217  Follow the above code. you can achieve your result